# Vuex store is being updated successfully, but the component is not picking up the update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuex

so ive this weird issue, and i have searched every question and forums, but nothing worked for me, my problem is that the `Calendar` component is not being updated, although the state inside the vuex store changes successfully as i viewed it in the vue dev tools. although the component is picking up the initial change of the vuex store, but subsequent commits to the store dosent seem to make the component update.

here is when im rendering the component

`index.html.erb`

```
  <calendar :month="<%= Date.current.month.to_json %>" :initial-events="<%= @events.to_json %>">

    <%= week_calendar events: @events, attribute: :begins_at do |date, events| %>
      <% events.each do |event| %>
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center text-gray-600 flex-col my-3" style="height: 100px;">
          <event
            :event="<%= event.with_formatted_dates.to_json %>"
          ></event>
        </div>
      <% end %>

    <% end %>
  </calendar>
```

here is the code of the `Calendar` component

`Calendar.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>you have {{allEvents.length}} items</h1>
      <slot></slot>

        <event :key="event.id" v-for="event in allEvents"
                :event="event"
        ></event>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapMutations, mapGetters } from "vuex";

    export default {
        name: "Calendar",
        props: ['initial-events'],
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['allEvents'])
        },
        created: function() {
            this.setEvents(
                this.$props.initialEvents
            );
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapMutations(['setEvents'])
        }
    }
</script>
```

as i said, the `Calendar` component picks up the initial update to the store, but subsequent updates is not being picked up. i am updating the store inside another component called `NewEvent.vue`

`NewEvent.vue`

```
//......
<script>
    import {mapMutations} from "vuex";
    export default {
        name: "NewEvent",
        methods: {
            ...mapMutations(['addEvent']),
            add: function () {
                this.addEvent({
                    name:"added new",
                    description: "some random description",
                    begins_at: new Date(),
                    ends_at: new Date(),
                    id: new Date().toString()
                })
            },
        }
    };
</script>
```

and here is the `events-store.js`

```
const state = {
    events: []
};

const getters = {
    allEvents: (state) => state.events,
};

const actions = {
    addEvent: ({ commit}, payload) => {
        commit("addEvent", payload);
    },
}

const mutations = {
    setEvents: (state, payload) => {
        state.events = payload;
    },
    addEvent: (state, payload) => {
        state= {
            events: [payload, ...state.events]
        };
    },
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
};
```

any help is greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: please share the store code

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim ive added the code to the store

Comment: what about `state.events.push(payload)` instead of `state= {events: [payload, ...state.events]}`?$

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim still no update, its still not updating